# awk: matching strings to decimal values and summing them

Tags: awk

I have strings that are supposed to match with numbers.

For example,

```
one is equal to 1
```

Now, I have a file that separates columns with ; and I want to write an awk expression that checks if the SUM of the first column $1 is equal to $2.

Here is an example of how the file is structured

```
oNe-oNE ; 2
one-too ; 1
```

**SOLUTION [needs improvement]
I have it working with only two arguments for the string, like one-one, but I need to adapt it to accept more, like One-TOO-pots-one-one (unlimited really).**

```
awk 'BEGIN{n=split("one 1 too 2 hello",b," ");for (i=1;i<n;i+=2) a[b[i]]=b[i+1]} {split($1,c,"-");f=tolower(c[1]);s=tolower(c[2]);print $0,"; "(a[f]+a[s]==$3?"match":"not")}' file
```

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given

```
oNe-oNE ; 2
one-too ; 1
One-TOO-pots-one-one ; 21
one-foo ; 1
```

then

```
awk -F\; '
BEGIN {
  val["one"]=1;val["too"]=2;val["hello"]=4;val["pots"]=16;
}

{
  split($1,a,"[- ]");
  t = 0;
  for (i in a) {
    t += val[tolower(a[i])];
  }
  if (t == $2) print $0, "match"; else print $0, "not";
}' file
```

produces

```
oNe-oNE ; 2 match
one-too ; 1 not
One-TOO-pots-one-one ; 21 match
one-foo ; 1 match
```

Comment: @Plaurs sorry, I don't understand what you're asking

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

1. Put string-to-number lines into a file of its own and parse it.
2. Manipulate `FS` to ease parsing of the CSV file.

One way to achieve this:

*sum.awk*

```
FNR==NR { h[$1] = $NF; next }
FNR==1  { FS=" *[-;] *"     }
{ print $0 " ; " (h[tolower($1)] + h[tolower($2)] == $3 ? "match" : "not") }
```

Run it like this:

```
awk -f sum.awk string-to-number.txt csv.txt
```

Output:

```
oNe-oNE ; 2 ; match
one-too ; 1 ; not
```